# Add required argument 'key'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I was trying to implement a feature where a user or users will be able to select the files from their phone storage or google drive but the problem is that I am getting an error "Add required argument key. The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument." . It was working fine before but now I am getting above error. The error I get is in line 42 where there is ButtonWidget.Please do comply.

```
import 'dart:io' show File;
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'firebase_api.dart';
import 'button_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class SubmitArticles extends StatefulWidget {
  const SubmitArticles({
    //added required to the key and child
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SubmitArticlesState createState() => _SubmitArticlesState();
}

class _SubmitArticlesState extends State<SubmitArticles> {
  late UploadTask task;
  late File file;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    final fileName = file != null ? basename(file.path) : 'No File Selected';
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Please Upload Your Article'),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context))),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ButtonWidget(
                    text: 'Select File',
                    icon: Icons.attach_file,
                    onClicked: selectFile,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Text(
                    fileName,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 48),
                  ButtonWidget(
                    text: 'Upload File',
                    icon: Icons.cloud_upload_outlined,
                    onClicked: uploadFile,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  task != null ? buildUploadStatus(task) : Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Future selectFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);

    future:
    if (result == null) return;
    final path = result.files.single.path;

    setState(() => file = File(path!));
  }

  Future<dynamic> uploadFile() async {
    future:
    if (file == null) return;

    final fileName = basename(file.path);
    final destination = 'articles/$fileName';

    task = FirebaseApi.uploadFile(destination, file)!;
    setState(() {});

    future:
    if (task == null) return;

    final snapshot = await task.whenComplete(() {});
    final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    print('Download-Link: $urlDownload');
  }

  Widget buildUploadStatus(UploadTask task) => StreamBuilder<TaskSnapshot>(
    stream: task.snapshotEvents,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      future:
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final snap = snapshot.data;
        final progress = snap!.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes;
        final percentage = (progress * 100).toStringAsFixed(2);

        return Text(
          '$percentage %',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        );
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide or check the code of the `ButtonWidget`. You might have set the key parameter to be required there.

Comment: class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onClicked;

  const ButtonWidget({
    Key key,this.icon,this.text,this.onClicked,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(context) => ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Colors.indigo,
      minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
    ),
    child: buildContent(),
    onPressed: onClicked,
  );

Comment: Just add `?` after `Key` type. Your new constructor will look like this `const ButtonWidget({ Key? key, this.icon, this.text, this.onClicked}) : super(key: key);`